# Installing Lispworks on rhel 6.5 Workstation. Error when loading application

Tags: rhel, system-installation, lisp

Does anybody know what this error means and how to get Lispworks Personal edition to run on Redhat?

Error:

```
Error during GUI startup:
Could not register handle for external module "-lgthread-2.0":
libgthread-2.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

Here is the whole output:

sudo /usr/bin/lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux

```
LispWorks(R): The Common Lisp Programming Environment Personal Edition
Copyright (C) 1987-2012 LispWorks Ltd.  All rights reserved.
Version 6.1.1
Saved by LispWorks as lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux, at 06 Dec 2012
16:51
User root on HostName
Error during GUI startup:
Could not register handle for external module "-lgthread-2.0":
libgthread-2.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or   
directory.

DESCRIPTION: Output Backtrace <and a simple test case, if possible>

IMPACT: Broken/Annoying/Data Loss/Missing Error/New Feature/Performance Loss

URGENCY: ASAP/Current Release/Next Release/Future Release/None



PRODUCT CONFIGURATION:

  LispWorks Personal Edition 6.1.1

Process name: /usr/bin/lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux
   ID: 9597    Started at: 2014/03/20 23:04:07

Save history:

1: lispworks-6-1-0-0-x86-linux-release-base
Saved by davef as lispworks-6-1-0-0-x86-linux-release-base, at 03 Nov 2011 13:25

2: lispworks-6-1-0-0-x86-linux-release-gtk-shaken
Saved by davef as lispworks-6-1-0-0-x86-linux-release-gtk-shaken, at 03 Nov 2011 14:00

3: lispworks-6-1-1-0-x86-linux-release-gtk-shaken
Saved by davef as lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux, at 06 Dec 2012 16:51
LispWorks 6.1.1 - Personal Edition

Loaded Modules: 

Public patches: 
Private patches:  CAPI-GTK-DESTROY-REPRESENTATION

Foreign modules:
  #<FLI::INTERNAL-MODULE :LISP : exports = 0>
  #<FLI::INTERNAL-MODULE :CALLBACKS : exports = 0>
  #<FLI::EXTERNAL-MODULE "-lgthread-2.0"  : handle = #x00000000; exports = 0>

Signal Handlers
2       SYSTEM::SIGINT-HANDLER
13      SYSTEM::THE-NULL-FUNCTION
17      SYSTEM::GET-CHILDREN-INF

HOST CONFIGURATION:

  Zundrum (x86_64), Linux 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64
  Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 6.5 (Santiago)
  Kernel \r on an \m

LWSerialNumber: Unknown

Site: Unknown

GTK+ not loaded

Backtrace:
#<The COMMON-LISP-USER package, 1/16 internal, 0/4 external>



Call to (SUBFUNCTION 1 ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT) {offset 186}
  SYSTEM::C : #<SIMPLE-ERROR 200C2DAB>

Binding frame:
  CONDITIONS::*IN-SIGNAL-CATCH* : T

Handler frame: NIL
Call to SIGNAL {offset 1446}
  CONDITIONS::DATUM     : #<SIMPLE-ERROR 200C2DAB>
  CONDITIONS::ARGUMENTS : NIL

Binding frame:
  CONDITIONS::*IN-SIGNAL-CATCH* : NIL

Catch frame: CONDITIONS::SIGNAL-CATCH

Binding frame:
  CONDITIONS::*BROKEN-ON-SIGNALS* : NIL

Call to CONDITIONS::CONDITIONS-ERROR {offset 430}
  CONDITIONS::DATUM     : "Could not register handle for external module ~S:~% ~A."
  CONDITIONS::ARGUMENTS : ("-lgthread-2.0" "libgthread-2.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory")

Call to ERROR {offset 67}
  SYSTEM::ESTRING : "Could not register handle for external module ~S:~% ~A."
  SYSTEM::EARGS   : ("-lgthread-2.0" "libgthread-2.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory")

Binding frame:
  FLI::*DLOPEN-FLAGS* : T

Call to FLI::CONNECT-TO-EXTERNAL-MODULE {offset 319}
  FLI::MODULE : #<FLI::EXTERNAL-MODULE "-lgthread-2.0"  : handle = #x00000000; exports = 0>
  TYPE        : :MANUAL
  FLI::ERRORP : T

Call to FLI::CREATE-EXTERNAL-MODULE {offset 275}
  FLI::NAME             : "-lgthread-2.0"
  FLI::CONNECTION-STYLE : :IMMEDIATE
  FLI::FILENAME         : NIL
  FLI::MODULE           : #<FLI::EXTERNAL-MODULE "-lgthread-2.0"  : handle = #x00000000; exports = 0>
  OPEN                  : T
  FLI::LIFETIME         : :SESSION
  FLI::DLOPEN-FLAGS     : FLI::DEFAULT
  FLI::ADD-LIB-PATH     : NIL

Call to FLI:REGISTER-MODULE {offset 146}
  FLI::NAME             : "-lgthread-2.0"
  FLI::CONNECTION-STYLE : :IMMEDIATE
  FLI::LIFETIME         : :SESSION
  FLI::REAL-NAME        : NIL
  FLI::FILE-NAME        : NIL
  FLI::DLOPEN-FLAGS     : FLI::DEFAULT
  FLI::ADD-LIB-PATH     : NIL

Call to LWGTK:INITIALIZE-GTK-LIBRARY {offset 999}

Call to CAPI-GTK-LIBRARY::ENSURE-GTK-INITIALIZED {offset 21}

Call to (METHOD CAPI-LIBRARY:LIBRARY-READY-TO-START ((EQL :GTK))) {offset 11}
  CAPI-GTK-LIBRARY::LOOK-AND-FEEL : :DONT-KNOW

Call to CLOS::CACHE-MISS-FUNCTION {offset 311}
  CLOS::ARGS                   : (:GTK)
  CLOS::.CACHE-INFO.  {Closed} : #<CLOS::CACHE-INFO CAPI-LIBRARY:LIBRARY-READY-TO-START [8/2] >
  CLOS::.GF.  {Closed}         : #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION CAPI-LIBRARY:LIBRARY-READY-TO-START 217FEBA2>

Call to CAPI-INTERNALS:START-ENVIRONMENT {offset 60}
  CAPI::ARGS            : (:START-FUNCTIONS ((LISPWORKS-TOOLS::START-LISPWORKS-TOOLS :TOOLS (LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISPWORKS-ECHO-PODIUM LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISTENER))) :ENVIRONMENT :CAPI)
  CAPI::ENVIRONMENT     : :CAPI
  PACKAGE               : NIL
  CAPI::LIBRARY         : NIL
  CAPI::START-FUNCTIONS : ((LISPWORKS-TOOLS::START-LISPWORKS-TOOLS :TOOLS (LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISPWORKS-ECHO-PODIUM LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISTENER)))

Call to ENVIRONMENT::START-CAPI-ENVIRONMENT {offset 24}
  LISPWORKS-TOOLS::ARGS : NIL

Call to CLOS::CACHE-MISS-FUNCTION {offset 311}
  CLOS::ARGS                   : (#<ENVIRONMENT::CAPI-ENVIRONMENT 21BCCF4B> NIL)
  CLOS::.CACHE-INFO.  {Closed} : #<CLOS::CACHE-INFO ENVIRONMENT-INTERNALS:ENVIRONMENT-START [8/2] >
  CLOS::.GF.  {Closed}         : #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION ENVIRONMENT-INTERNALS:ENVIRONMENT-START 20979E5A>

Handler frame: ((ERROR . #<Function 1 subfunction of ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT 21E1A0EA>))
Call to ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT {offset 158}
  SYSTEM::ARGS          : NIL
  SYSTEM::OLD  {Closed} : #<Function ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT 20979E92>

Binding frame:
  MP:*INITIAL-PROCESSES* : (("The idle process" (:PRIORITY -536870912 :RESTART-ACTION :CONTINUE :INTERNAL-SERVER :IDLE) MP::PROCESS-IDLE-FUNCTION))

Call to ENVIRONMENT::I-RESTART-WITH-ENVIRONMENT-AUX {offset 210}
  ENVIRONMENT::TTY-LISTENER-P : NIL

Call to SYSTEM::RESTART-HOOK {offset 96}
  FUNCTION : SYSTEM::%TOP-LEVEL

Restart frame: (SYSTEM::TOP-LEVEL)
Catch frame: (SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION-ONCE . RESTART-CASE)

Catch frame: (SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION-ONCE . 1)

Catch frame: SYSTEM::EXIT-LISPWORKS

Call to SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION-ONCE {offset 421}

Catch frame: SYSTEM::START-UP

Catch frame: SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION

Call to SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION {offset 57}

Call to SYSTEM::CALL-IN-START-FUNCTION {offset 12}

Catch frame: (NIL)

Call to SYSTEM::START-FUNCTION {offset 50}
  SYSTEM::GC-MESSAGES : :DONT-KNOW


SYSTEM::START-FUNCTION

 Generation 0:  Total Size 515K, Allocated 490K, Free 17K 
          Segment 20090128: Total Size 507K, Allocated 490K, Free 13K
                    minimum free space 64K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =10
          Segment 21EDE100: Total Size 7K, Allocated 0K, Free 3K
                    minimum free space 0K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =2
 Generation 1:  Total Size 308K, Allocated 110K, Free 189K 
          Segment 2070F0C0: Total Size 68K, Allocated 0K, Free 64K
                    minimum free space 3K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =4
          Segment 200540A8: Total Size 240K, Allocated 110K, Free 125K
                    minimum free space 0K, static
 Generation 2:  Total Size 68K, Allocated 0K, Free 64K 
          Segment 20F1C640: Total Size 68K, Allocated 0K, Free 64K
                    minimum free space 117K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =4
 Generation 3:  Total Size 30387K, Allocated 30247K, Free 128K 
          Segment 2010F0C0: Total Size 6144K, Allocated 6139K, Free 0K
                    minimum free space 3K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =10
          Segment 20F2D6B8: Total Size 16066K, Allocated 15934K, Free 128K
                    minimum free space 0K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =10
          Segment 20720138: Total Size 8177K, Allocated 8173K, Free 0K
                    minimum free space 0K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =10

Total Size 31616K, Allocated 30848K, Free 398K
```

EDIT: Here is the output from yum install glib2-devel

```
Setting up Install Process
Package glib2-devel-2.26.1-7.el6_5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Here is libgthread*.so

```
sudo find /*/*/libgthread*.so
/usr/lib64/libgthread-2.0.so
```

Here is ldd lispworks...

```
ldd /usr/bin/lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux 
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00a8b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00d45000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00402000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x0087e000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x0085c000)
```

EDIT: Here the error I get on my Fedora 20 x86_64 KDE

```
~]$ lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux 
LispWorks(R): The Common Lisp Programming Environment Personal Edition
Copyright (C) 1987-2012 LispWorks Ltd.  All rights reserved.
Version 6.1.1
Saved by LispWorks as lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux, at 06 Dec 2012 16:51
User root on Zundrum
Error during GUI startup:
  Could not register handle for external module "-lgtk-x11-2.0":
 libgtk-x11-2.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

DESCRIPTION: Output Backtrace <and a simple test case, if possible>

IMPACT: Broken/Annoying/Data Loss/Missing Error/New Feature/Performance Loss

URGENCY: ASAP/Current Release/Next Release/Future Release/None



PRODUCT CONFIGURATION:

  LispWorks Personal Edition 6.1.1

Process name: /home/kristjan/bin/lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux
   ID: 2527    Started at: 2014/03/25 18:37:44

Save history:

1: lispworks-6-1-0-0-x86-linux-release-base
Saved by davef as lispworks-6-1-0-0-x86-linux-release-base, at 03 Nov 2011 13:25

2: lispworks-6-1-0-0-x86-linux-release-gtk-shaken
Saved by davef as lispworks-6-1-0-0-x86-linux-release-gtk-shaken, at 03 Nov 2011 14:00

3: lispworks-6-1-1-0-x86-linux-release-gtk-shaken
Saved by davef as lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux, at 06 Dec 2012 16:51
LispWorks 6.1.1 - Personal Edition

Loaded Modules: 

Public patches: 
Private patches:  CAPI-GTK-DESTROY-REPRESENTATION

Foreign modules:
  #<FLI::INTERNAL-MODULE :LISP : exports = 0>
  #<FLI::INTERNAL-MODULE :CALLBACKS : exports = 0>
  #<FLI::EXTERNAL-MODULE "-lgthread-2.0"  {/lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0}: handle = #x09D30DE0; exports = 0>
  #<FLI::EXTERNAL-MODULE "-lgtk-x11-2.0"  : handle = #x00000000; exports = 0>

Signal Handlers
2       SYSTEM::SIGINT-HANDLER
13      SYSTEM::THE-NULL-FUNCTION
17      SYSTEM::GET-CHILDREN-INF

HOST CONFIGURATION:

  Zundrum (x86_64), Linux 3.13.6-200.fc20.x86_64
  Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug)
  Kernel \r on an \m (\l)

LWSerialNumber: Unknown

Site: Unknown

GTK+ not loaded

Backtrace:
#<The COMMON-LISP-USER package, 1/16 internal, 0/4 external>



Call to (SUBFUNCTION 1 ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT) {offset 186}
  SYSTEM::C : #<SIMPLE-ERROR 200B5DA3>

Binding frame:
  CONDITIONS::*IN-SIGNAL-CATCH* : T

Handler frame: NIL
Call to SIGNAL {offset 1446}
  CONDITIONS::DATUM     : #<SIMPLE-ERROR 200B5DA3>
  CONDITIONS::ARGUMENTS : NIL

Binding frame:
  CONDITIONS::*IN-SIGNAL-CATCH* : NIL

Catch frame: CONDITIONS::SIGNAL-CATCH

Binding frame:
  CONDITIONS::*BROKEN-ON-SIGNALS* : NIL

Call to CONDITIONS::CONDITIONS-ERROR {offset 430}
  CONDITIONS::DATUM     : "Could not register handle for external module ~S:~% ~A."
  CONDITIONS::ARGUMENTS : ("-lgtk-x11-2.0" "libgtk-x11-2.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory")

Call to ERROR {offset 67}
  SYSTEM::ESTRING : "Could not register handle for external module ~S:~% ~A."
  SYSTEM::EARGS   : ("-lgtk-x11-2.0" "libgtk-x11-2.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory")

Binding frame:
  FLI::*DLOPEN-FLAGS* : T

Call to FLI::CONNECT-TO-EXTERNAL-MODULE {offset 319}
  FLI::MODULE : #<FLI::EXTERNAL-MODULE "-lgtk-x11-2.0"  : handle = #x00000000; exports = 0>
  TYPE        : :MANUAL
  FLI::ERRORP : T

Call to FLI::CREATE-EXTERNAL-MODULE {offset 275}
  FLI::NAME             : "-lgtk-x11-2.0"
  FLI::CONNECTION-STYLE : :IMMEDIATE
  FLI::FILENAME         : NIL
  FLI::MODULE           : #<FLI::EXTERNAL-MODULE "-lgtk-x11-2.0"  : handle = #x00000000; exports = 0>
  OPEN                  : T
  FLI::LIFETIME         : :SESSION
  FLI::DLOPEN-FLAGS     : FLI::DEFAULT
  FLI::ADD-LIB-PATH     : NIL

Call to FLI:REGISTER-MODULE {offset 146}
  FLI::NAME             : "-lgtk-x11-2.0"
  FLI::CONNECTION-STYLE : :IMMEDIATE
  FLI::LIFETIME         : :SESSION
  FLI::REAL-NAME        : NIL
  FLI::FILE-NAME        : NIL
  FLI::DLOPEN-FLAGS     : FLI::DEFAULT
  FLI::ADD-LIB-PATH     : NIL

Call to LWGTK:INITIALIZE-GTK-LIBRARY {offset 999}

Call to CAPI-GTK-LIBRARY::ENSURE-GTK-INITIALIZED {offset 21}

Call to (METHOD CAPI-LIBRARY:LIBRARY-READY-TO-START ((EQL :GTK))) {offset 11}
  CAPI-GTK-LIBRARY::LOOK-AND-FEEL : :DONT-KNOW

Call to CLOS::CACHE-MISS-FUNCTION {offset 311}
  CLOS::ARGS                   : (:GTK)
  CLOS::.CACHE-INFO.  {Closed} : #<CLOS::CACHE-INFO CAPI-LIBRARY:LIBRARY-READY-TO-START [8/2] >
  CLOS::.GF.  {Closed}         : #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION CAPI-LIBRARY:LIBRARY-READY-TO-START 217FEBA2>

Call to CAPI-INTERNALS:START-ENVIRONMENT {offset 60}
  CAPI::ARGS            : (:START-FUNCTIONS ((LISPWORKS-TOOLS::START-LISPWORKS-TOOLS :TOOLS (LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISPWORKS-ECHO-PODIUM LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISTENER))) :ENVIRONMENT :CAPI)
  CAPI::ENVIRONMENT     : :CAPI
  PACKAGE               : NIL
  CAPI::LIBRARY         : NIL
  CAPI::START-FUNCTIONS : ((LISPWORKS-TOOLS::START-LISPWORKS-TOOLS :TOOLS (LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISPWORKS-ECHO-PODIUM LISPWORKS-TOOLS:LISTENER)))

Call to ENVIRONMENT::START-CAPI-ENVIRONMENT {offset 24}
  LISPWORKS-TOOLS::ARGS : NIL

Call to CLOS::CACHE-MISS-FUNCTION {offset 311}
  CLOS::ARGS                   : (#<ENVIRONMENT::CAPI-ENVIRONMENT 21BCCF4B> NIL)
  CLOS::.CACHE-INFO.  {Closed} : #<CLOS::CACHE-INFO ENVIRONMENT-INTERNALS:ENVIRONMENT-START [8/2] >
  CLOS::.GF.  {Closed}         : #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION ENVIRONMENT-INTERNALS:ENVIRONMENT-START 20979E5A>

Handler frame: ((ERROR . #<Function 1 subfunction of ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT 21E1A0EA>))
Call to ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT {offset 158}
  SYSTEM::ARGS          : NIL
  SYSTEM::OLD  {Closed} : #<Function ENVIRONMENT:START-ENVIRONMENT 20979E92>

Binding frame:
  MP:*INITIAL-PROCESSES* : (("The idle process" (:PRIORITY -536870912 :RESTART-ACTION :CONTINUE :INTERNAL-SERVER :IDLE) MP::PROCESS-IDLE-FUNCTION))

Call to ENVIRONMENT::I-RESTART-WITH-ENVIRONMENT-AUX {offset 210}
  ENVIRONMENT::TTY-LISTENER-P : NIL

Call to SYSTEM::RESTART-HOOK {offset 96}
  FUNCTION : SYSTEM::%TOP-LEVEL

Restart frame: (SYSTEM::TOP-LEVEL)
Catch frame: (SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION-ONCE . RESTART-CASE)

Catch frame: (SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION-ONCE . 1)

Catch frame: SYSTEM::EXIT-LISPWORKS

Call to SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION-ONCE {offset 421}

Catch frame: SYSTEM::START-UP

Catch frame: SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION

Call to SYSTEM::IN-START-FUNCTION {offset 57}

Call to SYSTEM::CALL-IN-START-FUNCTION {offset 12}

Catch frame: (NIL)

Call to SYSTEM::START-FUNCTION {offset 50}
  SYSTEM::GC-MESSAGES : :DONT-KNOW


SYSTEM::START-FUNCTION

 Generation 0:  Total Size 515K, Allocated 260K, Free 247K 
          Segment 20090128: Total Size 507K, Allocated 260K, Free 243K
                    minimum free space 64K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =10
          Segment 21EDE100: Total Size 7K, Allocated 0K, Free 3K
                    minimum free space 0K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =2
 Generation 1:  Total Size 308K, Allocated 110K, Free 189K 
          Segment 2070F0C0: Total Size 68K, Allocated 0K, Free 64K
                    minimum free space 3K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =4
          Segment 200540A8: Total Size 240K, Allocated 110K, Free 125K
                    minimum free space 0K, static
 Generation 2:  Total Size 68K, Allocated 0K, Free 64K 
          Segment 20F1C640: Total Size 68K, Allocated 0K, Free 64K
                    minimum free space 117K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =4
 Generation 3:  Total Size 30387K, Allocated 30247K, Free 128K 
          Segment 2010F0C0: Total Size 6144K, Allocated 6139K, Free 0K
                    minimum free space 3K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =10
          Segment 20F2D6B8: Total Size 16066K, Allocated 15934K, Free 128K
                    minimum free space 0K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =10
          Segment 20720138: Total Size 8177K, Allocated 8173K, Free 0K
                    minimum free space 0K, 
                      Awaiting promotion = 0K, sweeps before promotion =10

Total Size 31616K, Allocated 30618K, Free 628K
```

Comment: @derobert See my question edit. I installed some packages from rpmfind that where rpm's for fedora, can this be the problem?

Comment: can you locate the path for `libgthread*.so` file?

Comment: @SparKotॐ Found it see the edit.

Comment: `ldd /usr/bin/lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux` to see all lib dependencies are resolved; add `/usr/lib64/` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if `libgthread` was not mapped.

Comment: @SparKotॐ Done. See edit. I don't know how to add /usr/lib64 to LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Its not showing anything about libgthread.

Comment: it's as simple as `PATH` env variable; `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` prepending new to existing string. Apparently it's another binary(ELF) which depends on `libgthread` not `lispworks-personal` itself.

Comment: @SparKotॐ Thanks, I had some other issues so I installed Fedora 20 on the computer, I'll be using the rhel 6.5 Workstation some time in the future, but for now there's no Redhat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yei. It's working. This is what I did: I [read this post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgtk-x11-2-0-so-0-a-921435/)

He comes up with the solution in the end, so I installed:

```
~]$ sudo yum install gtk2.i686
```

It's fixed on my Fedora 20 x86_64 KDE, but I reckon it's the same on the rhel 6.5 Workstation. I also needed MonoDevelop, and to get that to work, I installed Fedora 20 KDE on my Rhel machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your platform is 64bit, but lispworks-personal-6-1-1-x86-linux is 32bit, so you should install libgthread.so 32bit.